# Getting Git commit count for a submodule?

Tags: git

I'm using `git rev-list --count master` to get the commit count of a Git repo. Is it possible to use `rev-list` with a submodule?

I know I can just `cd` to the submodule and `cd` back, but it'll be nice if it was 1 command.

Answer (score 0):

The `git submodule foreach` would seem a good fit for that

```
git submodule foreach 'echo $sm_path $(git rev-list --count master)'
```